# how to prevent back button from work on iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, attributes

i have a page that has several youtube link , this link work on iframe so when user click this link it embed youtube video and played in iframe im using html and jquery to make it like this:

Html:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Q5im0Ssyyus">Charlie 1</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QFCSXr6qnv4">Charlie 2</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/eaCCkfjPm0o">Charlie 3</a>
<iframe name="someFrame" id="someFrame" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#someFrame").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
})});
```

the problem is when user click back button in browser it back in iframe not the page so you need to clicked several time to go back to the page you whant any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

how about you remove the jquery code and add `target="someFrame"` to your link tag, where "someFrame" is the id of the iframe like this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Q5im0Ssyyus" target="someFrame">Charlie 1</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QFCSXr6qnv4" target="someFrame">Charlie 2</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/eaCCkfjPm0o" target="someFrame">Charlie 3</a>
<iframe name="someFrame" id="someFrame" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

Comment: maybe the hol code is wrong i don't know can you try to make another code and don't affect the browser

Comment: i don't know what exactly affect the browser is it the iframe or the link